# Выбор падежа в названии справки

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, падежи

В Гугле можно видеть следующую устоявшуюся на практике фразу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но разве это не ошибка? Ведь правильно:

> Справка об имуществе (каком?), принадлежащем налогоплательщику на
> праве собственности и не находящегося под обременением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, причастие (второе, кстати, тоже) необходимо согласовать с определяемым существительным, стоящим в предложном падеже:

*Справка об имуществе, принадлежащ**ем** налогоплательщику на праве собственности и не находящ**емся** под обременением.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]